# Rotate by hover in css

Tags: jquery, css

```
#square{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: magenta;
        margin: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}
.rotate{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 5.0s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 5.0s;
    -o-transition-duration: 5.0s;
    transition-duration: 5.0s;        
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;        
    overflow:hidden;    
}   
.rotate:hover{ 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

My code is about hover the item and it will rotate around itself.

But I want to know how it can be sensitive-hover like, when I drag mouse across the item it will be rotate by how speed that the mouse moving across.

It looks like spinning the wheel.

Comment: You can't do this using CSS, you'll need to resort to using Javascript.

Comment: #Timothy Groote can you suggest me what does it call in JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8BwLd/)**

**css**

```
#square {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: magenta;
        margin: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    }
.rotate{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 5.0s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 5.0s;
    -o-transition-duration: 5.0s;
    transition-duration: 5.0s;

    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;

    overflow:hidden;

    }   
.rotate:hover   
{ 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(360deg); 
-o-transform: rotate(360deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); 
}
```